# Why I can use both `Name` and `Key` to get the key in `$hashTable.GetEnumerator()`?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm a novice in PowerShell. Recently, I've been using a hashtable in PowerShell and getting the keys and values of it.

For example, there is a hashtable as:

```
$hashTable=@{
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
}
```

And if get the keys and values separately:

```
$hashTable.Keys
# c,a,b
$hashTable.Values
# 3,1,2
```

I understand the disorganization of a hashtable. And there is no property `Names` as the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=net-7.0#properties).

But, when it comes to the method `GetEnumerator()`:

```
$hashTable.GetEnumerator()
```

It shows as the following:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
c                              3
a                              1
b                              2
```

My question is, why the header is `Name-Value` but not `Key-Value`, I think it should be consistent with its original hashtable's properties.

Then I do the following tests, but they all work:

```
$hashTable.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property Key                                                                               

# Name                           Value
# ----                           -----
# a                              1
# b                              2
# c                              3

$hashTable.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property Name

# Name                           Value
# ----                           -----
# a                              1
# b                              2
# c                              3
```

So, it seems that `Name` equals `Key` in `hashTable.GetEnumerator()`.
Is there any explanation or reason for this design or phenomenon? Why not design it to allow only `Key`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell allows you to define what is known as [**Alias Property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/ets/properties?view=powershell-7.3#alias-property) for specified types or instances.

`Name` happens to be an Alias Property added to the [`DictionaryEntry` instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.dictionaryentry?view=net-7.0):

```bash
$getMemberSplat = @{
    InputObject = [System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]::new('foo', 'bar')
    MemberType  = 'AliasProperty'
}

Get-Member @getMemberSplat

# Outputs:
#
#   TypeName: System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
#
# Name MemberType    Definition
# ---- ----------    ----------
# Name AliasProperty Name = Key
```

We can see that the property is an *extended member* of `DictionaryEntry` using [`Get-TypeData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-typedata?view=powershell-7.3):

```bash
(Get-TypeData System.Collections.DictionaryEntry).Members['Name']

# ReferencedMemberName MemberType IsHidden Name
# -------------------- ---------- -------- ----
# Key                                False Name
```

Alias Properties can be added to a specified type using [`Update-TypeData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-typedata?view=powershell-7.3), for example:

```bash
$updateTypeDataSplat = @{
    TypeName   = 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo'
    MemberType = 'AliasProperty'
    MemberName = 'AbsolutePath'
    Value      = 'FullName'
}

Update-TypeData @updateTypeDataSplat

# Now using the new Alias Property:
(Get-Item $pwd).AbsolutePath
# Should be the same as:
(Get-Item $pwd).FullName
```

They can also be added to instances of a type with [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-7.3), for example:

```bash
$myObject = [pscustomobject]@{
    MyProperty = 'hi'
}

$addMemberSplat = @{
    InputObject = $myObject
    MemberType  = 'AliasProperty'
    Name        = 'MyAliasProperty'
    Value       = 'MyProperty'
}

Add-Member @addMemberSplat

$myObject.MyAliasProperty # hi
```

And, for custom types, can be defined through a [`Types.ps1xml` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.3), the linked PowerShell doc has a mention on the [built-in type system and the built-in defined aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.3#built-in-typesps1xml-files):

> For example, by default, array objects (`System.Array`) have a `Length` property that lists the number of objects in the array. However, because the name `Length` does not clearly describe the property, PowerShell adds an **alias property** named `Count` that displays the same value.

---

Worth noting here that `.Count` should've never been an Alias Property in PowerShell 5.1 since `.Count` is an array's [Explicit Interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-7.0#explicit-interface-implementations). In PowerShell 7+ we no longer see `.Count` as an Alias Property but as just `Property`:

```bash
# PowerShell 7.4
PS ..\pwsh> Get-Member -InputObject @() -Name Count

   TypeName: System.Object[]

Name  MemberType Definition
----  ---------- ----------
Count Property   int Count {get;}

# Windows PowerShell 5.1
PS ..\pwsh> powershell 'Get-Member -InputObject @() -Name Count'


   TypeName: System.Object[]      

Name  MemberType    Definition    
----  ----------    ----------    
Count AliasProperty Count = Length
```

Ideally, in my opinion, we should the definition as `int ICollection.Count {get;}`.

---

As for, why do you see **`Name` and `Value`** instead of **`Key` and `Value`**, this is defined by the built-in format files, in this case, the one that targets the `DictionaryEntry` type. You can see this by yourself:

```bash
Get-FormatData System.Collections.DictionaryEntry |
    Export-FormatData -Path DictionaryEntry.format.ps1xml

Get-Content DictionaryEntry.format.ps1xml
```

Fragment below is an extract of the `format.ps1xml` for `DictionaryEntry`. See [**about_Format.ps1xml**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.3) for more details.

```xml
    <View>
      <Name>Dictionary</Name>
      <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>System.Collections.DictionaryEntry</TypeName>
      </ViewSelectedBy>
      <TableControl>
        <TableHeaders>
          <TableColumnHeader>
            <Width>30</Width>
          </TableColumnHeader>
          <TableColumnHeader />
        </TableHeaders>
        <TableRowEntries>
          <TableRowEntry>
            <TableColumnItems>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>Name</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>Value</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
            </TableColumnItems>
          </TableRowEntry>
        </TableRowEntries>
      </TableControl>
    </View>
```

Comment: Nicely done; worth mentioning that `.Count` is no longer an ETS property in PowerShell Core: `Get-Member -InputObject @() Count` (implicitly provided via the `ICollection` interface now, from what I can tell).

Comment: @mklement0 not in C# at least that I can tell. if you wanted to use the `.Count` you would need to `((ICollection) arr).Count`

Comment: @mklement0 it's hard to describe it, `.Count` has always been an explicit interface implementation, before and now. It should've always been shown as a `Property` and not as `Alias property`. Ideally it should be shown as `int ICollection.Count {get;} ¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Indeed, in C# you must cast to the interface. If memory serves, the backstory in PowerShell is: v3 introduced automatically surfacing even explicit interface implementations, so the ETS property has been redundant ever since, but wasn't removed until PowerShell Core came along. Therefore, in v5.1, if you run `Remove-TypeData System.Array`, `.Count` will continue to work, because the `ICollection` implementation then surfaces. Unfortunately, the Windows PowerShell ETS definition isn't just redundant, but causes problem during JSON serialization: `ConvertTo-Json (New-Object int[] 2)`

Comment: @mklement0 yeah thats very unfortunate. It's hard to tell what were they thinking on 5.1. Even reading back that extract from types.ps1xml is misleading, it could be misinterpreted as array not implementing ICollection in NET Framework...

Comment:  P.S.: To see where `.Count` comes from in PowerShell Core / after having run `Remote-TypeData System.Array` in Windows PowerShell, use `Get-Member -InputObject @() get_Count -Force`